# Cannot neutrally charged objects describe the effects of dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter

For the galaxy cluster that dark matter describes: I think the picture would be something like a shell. The outer layer would be the galaxies and the inner layer would be n-bodies of neutrally charged objects that are held together in orbits.

Is this a plausible idea?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what would prevent the inner neutral objects from mixing with the outer layer? Also, note that neutralilty does not imply inability to emit electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is - dark matter *must* be electrically neutral because it's *dark*, what's layers are you talking about? "n bodies of neutrally charged objects" is a pretty good description of solar systems, which are obviously not dark matter, so it's not really clear what you are thinking about here.

Comment: Keep in mind that we see *through* clusters (and indeed galaxies) in various bands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For a start large-scale accumulations of matter, such as stars, gas clouds, planets and people *are* neutrally charged to a very good approximation.  Yet these things emit plenty of EM radiation when they are hot.

So, perhaps we could consider matter made *only* out of, for instance, neutrons.  Unfortunately that doesn't work either for at least two reasons: such matter doesn't exist other than in very particular circumstances such as neutron stars, and neutrons have both magnetic moments and charge distributions which means that, for instance, neutron stars often have huge magnetic fields and are often extremely bright electromagnetically.

So, perhaps we could consider some other kind of particle which really does not interact electromagnetically at all.  Well, yes, we could.  And that's well on the way to the kind of dark matter that people talk about.  I'll leave someone more expert than me to fill in the details of other things that can be ruled out (such as neutrinos, I think).

Comment: Neutrinos are so light they are normally relativistic. Dark matter is usually cold and slower.